# How can i use API with axios on React-Native

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, axios

i am  a student and i began to develop mobile application about books.
I am trying to get random books list with use axios and api.
I am beginner in React-Native so i tried to find how can I use but many tutorial videos use components for create an app.I use functions.
I found some codes for help me but this codes belongs to React.js .
I couldnt convert to React-Native.
Here are the codes.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View,Text,Button,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import Axios from 'axios';



const ExploreScreen = () => {
    const [book,setBook] = useState("");
        const [result,setResult] = useState([]);
        const [apiKey,setApiKey] = useState("AIzaSyBW3SP0vixN1EX8VueI9VL5wzbbjTm")

    function handleChange(event){
        const book =event.target.value;
        setBook(book);
    }

    function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        axios.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+book+"&key="+apiKey+"&maxResults=40")
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.data.items);
            setResult(data.data.items)
        })
    }

    return (
        <View style={StyleSheet.contianer}>
            <TextInput
            onChangeText={() => handleChange()}></TextInput>
            <TouchableOpacity
                title="Click here"
                onPress={() => handleSubmit()}/>
            {result.map(book =>(
                <a target="_blank" href={book.volumeInfo.previewLink}>
                <Image src={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail} alt={bookTitle}
                />
                </a>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
};
export default ExploreScreen;

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    contianer: {
        flex:1,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    }
})
```

Comment: So what isn't working?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: I just see blank page with input.But when i try to write something to input area it says **undefined is not an object evualating.event.target**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't watched it closely, but the error you are referring:

> undefined is not an object evualating.event.target

is because both `onChangeText` and `onPress` have no arguments, thus event is undefined when the function is called.

You should instead pass the event as an argument, for example:

```
onChangeText={event => handleChange(event)}
```

You can find an example of both components with examples on the documentation:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity